Shadcn dialog and react-select position issue (z-index)
I want to render react-select dropdown inside shadcn dialog. I'm rendering select using portal to document.body and the problem is that once it is open, I cannot click it because its somehow rendered behind the dialog. Here is how it looks like in devtools:

Dialog has position fixed with z-index set to 50 and select is rendred after with z-idnex set to 9999. Even though It appers on top of dialog, I cannot click it. Any suggestions?

Sounds like a typical styling error, need more information, can you provide the code from the component? incl. the css (looks like you use tailwind).
Also, how does the state management look like?
I assume you code looks something like this:
import React from 'react';
import * as Dialog from '@radix-ui/react-dialog';
import './styles.css';
import Select from 'react-select'


const options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
  ]

const DialogWithReactSelect = () => (
  <Dialog.Root>
    <Dialog.Trigger asChild>
      <button className="Button violet">Open Dialog</button>
    </Dialog.Trigger>
    <Dialog.Portal>
      <Dialog.Overlay className="DialogOverlay" />
      <Dialog.Content className="DialogContent">
        <Dialog.Title className="DialogTitle">This is a dialog</Dialog.Title>
        <Dialog.Description className="DialogDescription">
          This dialog contains a react-select component.
        </Dialog.Description>

        <Select options={options} />
 
      </Dialog.Content>
    </Dialog.Portal>
  </Dialog.Root>
);

export default DialogWithReactSelect;




I had the same issue where I couldn't click on react-select after it opened.
To fix it, set react-select to use a portal and set pointerEvents to 'auto'. This allows react-select to interact with pointer events and ensures it’s visible at the UI level.
  <Select
    options={[
      { value: "test", label: "Test" }
    ]}
    menuPortalTarget={document.body}
    styles={{
      menuPortal: (base) => ({ ...base, pointerEvents: "auto" })
    }}
  />

